# How to remove a variable x from inside a summation in the form $f(x) = \sum_{i} \frac{1}{x - D_i}$?

Tags: functions, summation, inverse-function

While trying to make a function to be put into a computer shader, i've come up with an expression in the following form:
$$f(x) = \sum_{i} \frac{1}{x - D_i}$$

But the thing is that i actually need the inverse of that function for it to do what i want

But i have not enough math knowledge to actually come up with that function inverse, if there even exists one

Obs: D is an arbitrary list of numbers

How would i come up with the inverse of that function, or if doesn't exists, why?

Comment: The inverse might be more than 1 answers. Do you want all possible inversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-10}
$$
and let's say that $x = 1, 3, 10$ are the "special" points.

If we pick an $x$ that's just a tiny bit greater than one of the special points, say $x = 3.00001$, then the first term will be about $1/2$l the third will be about $1/(-7)$, and the middle one will be...about $10,000$. By adjusting $x$ a tiny bit, you could get any number from $9000$ to $11000$, although finding exactly the right $x$ could be tricky because of the other terms and their slowly-changing values as you diddle with $x$.

You could do exactly the same thing with $x = 10.00001$, once again producing any output between $9000$ and $11000$.

But that shows you that this function (or any other function that looks like it) is not one-to-one, i.e., there are two different $x$ values that produce the same $y$-value. So it does not have an inverse.

Sorry to disappoint you, but that's the way it is.

(By the way, if you use Desmos to plot the function I described, it'll be visually clear that almost any horizontal line intersects the graph at multiple locations.)

Comment: Oh, i got it. It's sad tho.
I'm using this formula to create a 2D mesh deform shader that uses control points to deform the positions of pixels

The thing is that having a pixel at (x, y), i came up with a formula that calculate the new pixel position at (x', y'), but thats not how shaders work.

What i actually need to do is, having a point at (x', y'), i need to find the pixel at (x, y) that actually maps into that position, hence, why i needed the inverse function

Oh well, i'll have to come up with another solution then

Comment: But, like, isn't there any more generic formula that can give me all the possible inversions? Thinking about your example, i would assume that the maximum number of different solutions can't be more than the list size, as you can only get to 10,000 by going near one of the 3 special cases. It doesn't have an infinite amount of solutions, does it?

Comment: The usual solution is something that gets called "radial basis functions" (which you're sneaking up on with your $1/(x-d_i)$ thing).

Comment: No...if you sum up $k$ things like that, it'll typically produce $k$ inverses for every possible output value. (There's actually a lovely theory in complex variables that gives details of this, and essentially lets you define the notion of the "degree" of a smooth complex map). Still, if you want to move each $P_i$ to $Q_i$, you can equally well express that by saying that you want each $Q_i$ to "come from" $P_i$.

Comment: wow, it makes sense, since $x-D_i$ in the formula is actually a distance function where i check the distance from the pixel to one of the control points, and invert it to get a factor of how much this control point affects the pixel being distorted

Comment: I think you've got the idea. I'd write some code for you, but I'm busy debugging my own code right now. :(